# Authorization Credentials sparql

Tags: android, authentication, sparql, resultset

I am newbie in sparql queries. I try to send a sparql query from my android device to an     EndPointURI remote server so i can get the results. I want to select all the results that     match with "salmon", as it seems in my code below.
My issue is in this line: "ResultSet resultSet = qe.execSelect();".
When i try to take the results i get
no authentication challenges found at libcore.net.http.httpURLConnectionImpl.get     Authorization Credentials
and this because myURL wants authentication credentials and i dont know how to send them.
Any ideas of how can i send username and password succesfully?
My imports are :

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;    
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;    
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;    
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;    
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;    
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Syntax;
```

the .jars in my libs file are:

```
androjena_0.5,    
arqoid_0.5,    
icu4j_3_4,   
iri-0.8,   
lucenoid_3.0.2,    
slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1
```

and finally my function

```
public String queryRemoteSparqlEndpoint()    
{    
      String username="lala";    
      String password="lala";    
      String queryString = "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> select ?sp"    
       +where {"   
       +"<URL>"    
       +"?sp \"salmon\"."    
       +"}";    

     String sparqlEndpointUri = "myURL/sparql";    

     Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString, Syntax.syntaxARQ);   

     query.setLimit(10);    

       Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {    
      @Override    
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {    
          return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());    
      }    
  });

     QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(sparqlEndpointUri, query);

     ResultSet resultSet = qe.execSelect();       
     while (resultSet.hasNext())    
     {    
       //.....
     }    
     return results.toString();      
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of Jena is being run in androjena 0.5 but the current version of Jena has support for

```
sparqlService(String service, Query query, HttpAuthenticator authenticator)
```

where `HttpAuthenticator` is from Apache HTTP Client.  I don't know if this works on androjena.

If the code does not support it, you can make the call directly with native HTTP operations and pass the resulting input stream to a result set parser (see `ResultSetFactory`).

Comment: Thanks for response.
androjena0.5 unfortunately does not support 
sparqlService(String , Query , HttpAuthenticator ).
Also i cannot import jena.jar instead.
I try 
    HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();    
    CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();    
    provider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST,    
    AuthScope.ANY_PORT), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username,     password));    
    httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER, provider); 
But it still not working. In this case what i supposed to do?   
Thank you :)